# Google visualisation set chart colour

Tags: colors, google-visualization, bar-chart

No matter what I try all the bars come out the same colour as the first defined one in the colours option, can anyone show me how to make each bar a different colour?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Browser');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sprites @ 30 FPS');
        data.addRows([
        ['IE9 (2D)', 4681],
        ['Chrome 15 (2D)', 4121],
        ['Firefox 8 (2D)', 3292]
        ]);
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, { width: 650, height: 400, legend: "none",
            colors:['red','blue','green'],
            hAxis: { title: 'Browser'},
            vAxis: { minValue: 0 },
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width:650; height:400"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'colors' option specifies the colours used for each of your column groups. Right now, you only have one 'Sprites @ 30 FPS'. Adding extra columns allows you to take advantage of the difference colours; for example, change your code to the following:

```
    data.addColumn('string', 'Browser');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sprites @ 30 FPS');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Column 3');
    data.addRows([
    ['IE9 (2D)', 4681, 3000],
    ['Chrome 15 (2D)', 4121, 2000],
    ['Firefox 8 (2D)', 3292, 5000]
    ]);
```

to see the red and blue columns displayed (and so on..).

Alternatively, you may find more flexibility with the image chart generator. [Here's](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=bvg&chs=100x75&chd=t:5|10|15&chds=0,120&chco=4d89f9,c6d9fd,00B88A&chds=0,20&chbh=a&chxs=0,000000,0,0,_&chxt=y&chm=N,000000,0,,10|N,000000,1,,10|N,000000,2,,10) a sample url close to what you need, see the [full documentation here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/bar_charts.html).